# Issue with Trackpy - InvalidIndexError when fitting EMSD to a power law from the tutorial

Tags: python, pandas, trackpy

possibly a silly problem, but I'm stuck and I'd really appreciate someone's help. I'm trying to replicate the examples given in the walkthrough tutorial for trackpy (https://soft-matter.github.io/trackpy/dev/tutorial/walkthrough.html). I've been succesful up until I got to the point where I had to fit the ensemble mean-squared displacement to a power law (In [34]):

```
plt.figure()
plt.ylabel(r'$\langle \Delta r^2 \rangle$ [$\mu$m$^2$]')
plt.xlabel('lag time $t$');
tp.utils.fit_powerlaw(em)  # performs linear best fit in log space, plots]
```

This is the error message I get. Can someone suggest a solution?
Thanks!

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx:142, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), None)' is an invalid key

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

InvalidIndexError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [178], in <cell line: 4>()
      2 plt.ylabel(r'$\langle \Delta r^2 \rangle$ [$\mu$m$^2$]')
      3 plt.xlabel('lag time $t$');
----> 4 tp.utils.fit_powerlaw(em)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trackpy/utils.py:50, in fit_powerlaw(data, plot, **kwargs)
     48 if plot:
     49     from trackpy import plots
---> 50     plots.fit(data, fits, logx=True, logy=True, legend=False, **kwargs)
     51 return values

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trackpy/plots.py:50, in make_axes.<locals>.wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     47 # Delete legend keyword so remaining ones can be passed to plot().
     48 legend = kwargs.pop('legend', False)
---> 50 result = func(*args, **kwargs)
     52 if legend:
     53     handles, labels = kwargs['ax'].get_legend_handles_labels()

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trackpy/plots.py:652, in fit(data, fits, inverted_model, logx, logy, ax, **kwargs)
    650     ax.set_yscale('log')
    651 if not inverted_model:
--> 652     fitlines = ax.plot(fits.index, fits, **kwargs)
    653 else:
    654     fitlines = ax.plot(fits.reindex(data.dropna().index),
    655                        data.dropna(), **kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py:1632, in Axes.plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1390 """
   1391 Plot y versus x as lines and/or markers.
   1392 
   (...)
   1629 (``'green'``) or hex strings (``'#008000'``).
   1630 """
   1631 kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D)
-> 1632 lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1633 for line in lines:
   1634     self.add_line(line)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:312, in _process_plot_var_args.__call__(self, data, *args, **kwargs)
    310     this += args[0],
    311     args = args[1:]
--> 312 yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py:488, in _process_plot_var_args._plot_args(self, tup, kwargs, return_kwargs)
    486 if len(xy) == 2:
    487     x = _check_1d(xy[0])
--> 488     y = _check_1d(xy[1])
    489 else:
    490     x, y = index_of(xy[-1])

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/cbook/__init__.py:1327, in _check_1d(x)
   1321 with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
   1322     warnings.filterwarnings(
   1323         "always",
   1324         category=Warning,
   1325         message='Support for multi-dimensional indexing')
-> 1327     ndim = x[:, None].ndim
   1328     # we have definitely hit a pandas index or series object
   1329     # cast to a numpy array.
   1330     if len(w) > 0:

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:3628, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3623         raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624     except TypeError:
   3625         # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626         #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627         #  the TypeError.
-> 3628         self._check_indexing_error(key)
   3629         raise
   3631 # GH#42269

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py:5637, in Index._check_indexing_error(self, key)
   5633 def _check_indexing_error(self, key):
   5634     if not is_scalar(key):
   5635         # if key is not a scalar, directly raise an error (the code below
   5636         # would convert to numpy arrays and raise later any way) - GH29926
-> 5637         raise InvalidIndexError(key)

InvalidIndexError: (slice(None, None, None), None)
```